# Entity Framework Multiple EDMX file sharing same tables

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity

**Environment** : EF 6, SQL 2012

**Setup**: Database First, LazyLoading disabled

The question might appear more generic but will try to explain it in the best possible way.

I have a large application using ASP.NET MVC and grouped the entity based on the logical functionality. Hence we built multiple EDMX files

There is scenario in which we have to use the similar entity in two EDMX file.

`School` has relation to `Teachers` and `Students`.In first EDMX file, i used `school` and `Teachers`.In Second EDMX file, i used `school` and `students`

But only one Entity class getting created. If i run the custom tool on second EDMX context file, then the entity`(school.cs)` on my first edmx getting disappeared and it appears on the second one..

- Why this strange behaviour occurs?

Here is the code in my first EDMX file

As you see here, i m not accessing `school` entity and also i disabled Lazyloading. But it complains that it couldnt find `school` file. Note: Courses has navigation property to school. But i didnt include it here.. **Why its occuring so?**

```
 var courses= DB.courses
                                        .AsNoTracking()
                                        .Select(e =>
                                            new CourseDTO()
                                            {
                                                CourseID= e.CourseID,
                                                Name= e.CourseName,
                                                Desc= e.Desc,
                                                isActive= e.isActive
                                            })
                                        .OrderBy(e => e.CourseID);
```

The problem is, I m able to include one entity in the EDMX file only..
In first EDMX, it has navigation property to Teachers
In second EDMX , it has navigation property related to Students. But only Entity file exists at a time.. With only one Entity file, the code breaks 
Note: This is just sample..Not my original application

Comment: Rename the entity name in one of the edmx files, for instance `TeacherSchool`.

Comment: @GertArnold, i updated the soln, which worked for me.. But if there is any mistake, please help me to resolve ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @GertArnold. Meanwhile, i tried to create folders and kept the EDMX file inside it. Means i created seperate folder for each logical group and then included edmx file inside it. This in turn made the edmx file entities have different name space(i mean the entity classes) and also it enabled to have the same entity across multiple EDMX files. It sounds to have resolved my problem.

**I didnt try to have them included under different namespace.. The whole idea started when i realized that even though i have two EDMX files, the associated entities(.csfiles) are created in the same physical location. I tried to create sub folders and included the EDMX files. It resolved the problem and i found it is having different name space**

:):)

Comment: I think the classes should still have different names, because EF ignores (or ignoreD by now?) namespaces when it discovers entity types.

Comment: @GertArnold. So far so good Gert.. I m accessing the entity from both EDMX file and not encountering any issues.. The reason i m not prepared to go with entity name change is, when i do a refresh, the name change gets reverted

Comment: No, the changed class name will not be reverted by an update.

Comment: @GertArnold.. One last question, i m using Database First approach... I m disabling the Lazyloading in the constructor of entity class and its reverted everytime , when i do model update from DB.. How we can prevent it.. And to your name change, i m sure the entity name will be reverted , once updated from DB.. Here is the autogenerated code
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.//

Comment: Did not work for me, entity framework 6 ignores Namespaces